# CLI: getOptionValue always return 'null'

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

```
public class converter {

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Options opt = new Options();

    opt.addOption("I", "in", false, "Eingabeformat (2,8,10,16)");
    opt.addOption("O", "out", false, "Ausgabeformat (2,8,10,16)");
    opt.addOption("V", "value", true, "Zu konvertierende Zahl");

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    String value = "0";
    String in = "0";
    String out = "0";
    int inInt = 0; 
    int outInt = 0;

    try {
        CommandLine cl = parser.parse(opt, args);

        if (cl.hasOption("I")) {
            in = cl.getOptionValue("I");
            System.out.println(in); 
        } else if (cl.hasOption("in")) {
            in = cl.getOptionValue("in");
            inInt = Integer.parseInt(in);  
        }

        if (cl.hasOption("O")) {
            out = cl.getOptionValue("O");
            outInt = Integer.parseInt(out); 
        } else if (cl.hasOption("out")) {
            out = cl.getOptionValue("out");
            outInt = Integer.parseInt(out); 
        }

        if (cl.hasOption("V")) {
            value = cl.getOptionValue("V");
        } else if (cl.hasOption("value")) {
            value = cl.getOptionValue("value");
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hello, for my classes I have to learn to work with CLI and it looks ok for now. My problem is: the variable 'in' always return null after using cl.getOptionValue("I") on it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you expect the args *I, O* and *V* to have option values, otherwise you would not try to parse them. But you only specify that for the *V* option by setting the third argument in the call of `addOption` to true. You should set them all to `true` if you want to specify option values:

```
    opt.addOption("I", "in", true, "Eingabeformat (2,8,10,16)");
    opt.addOption("O", "out", true, "Ausgabeformat (2,8,10,16)");
    opt.addOption("V", "value", true, "Zu konvertierende Zahl");
```

btw you should name your class `Converter`with an uppercase 'C', that's Java convention.

Comment: The task was that the args "value" and "v" should be mandatory and the args I, in, O, out are optional. My first toughts were to make them false, so the user doesnt need to input them if he doesnt want to. But i actually reworked my class, so the task should be fulfilled - watch my commant on the theard.

Comment: Btw Thanks for your help, appricate!

Comment: well if my answer solved your problem, it would be nice to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class converter {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Options opt = new Options();

    opt.addOption("I", "in", true, "Eingabeformat (2,8,10,16)"); // Bei false gibts spaeter null
    opt.addOption("O", "out", true, "Ausgabeformat (2,8,10,16)"); // Bei false gibt spaeter null
    opt.addOption("V", "value", true, "Zu konvertierende Zahl");

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    String value = "0";
    String in, out;
    int inInt = 10; 
    int outInt = 10;

    try {
        CommandLine cl = parser.parse(opt, args);

        if (cl.hasOption("I")) {
            in = cl.getOptionValue("I");
            inInt = Integer.parseInt(in);
        } else if (cl.hasOption("in")) {
            in = cl.getOptionValue("in");
            inInt = Integer.parseInt(in);
        }

        if (cl.hasOption("O")) {
            out = cl.getOptionValue("O");
            outInt = Integer.parseInt(out);
        } else if (cl.hasOption("out")) {
            out = cl.getOptionValue("out");
            outInt = Integer.parseInt(out);
        }

        if (cl.hasOption("V")) {
            value = cl.getOptionValue("V");
            System.out.println(convert(value, inInt, outInt));
        } else if (cl.hasOption("value")) {
            value = cl.getOptionValue("value");
            System.out.println(convert(value, inInt, outInt));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Keinen Wert eingegeben. Erneut Versuchen!");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static String convert(String input, int srcRadix, int dstRadix) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(input, srcRadix);
    return Integer.toString(value, dstRadix);
}
```

}